# Is there any difference between background-clip and background-origin?

Tags: html, css, background

The CSS3 declarations `background-clip` and `background-origin` seem to have the same effect on the background. They both appear to restrict the background to a certain area relative to the HTML element, so I was wondering if there really is a difference in function of these two declarations.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to the MDN:

> The **background-clip** CSS property specifies whether an element's
> background, either the color or image, extends underneath its border.

while

> The **background-origin** CSS property determines the background
> positioning area, that is the position of the origin of an image
> specified using the background-image CSS property.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-clip
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-origin

Both properties have three options: `border-box`, `padding-box`, and `content-box`. The `background-origin` property determines where the background is placed (defaulting to padding-box) while the `background-clip` determines what part of the background is shown (defaulting to border-box). The properties can be used together or independently.

Some examples may be useful:

- [Default](https://jsfiddle.net/8jwv1hkd/2/) (neither property specified)

**Background-origin**

- [Background-origin set to `border-box`](https://jsfiddle.net/hy17g8ax/12/) - Notice how the background image has been shifted slightly up and to the left so that the origin of its position is under the border of the div (the border has been made transparent to help visualize this).
- [Background-origin set to `padding-box`](https://jsfiddle.net/8749mx5z/3/) (default) - Since the `padding-box` value is the default value, this should look the same as the default example.
- [Background-origin set to `content-box`](https://jsfiddle.net/s9Lv2q0u/4/) - Notice how the background image has been shifted slightly down and right so that the origin of its position is the content area of the div, which is determined by the padding applied to the div.

**Background-clip**

- [Background-clip set to `border-box`](https://jsfiddle.net/0u2nezxv/5/) (default) - Here there is no difference from the default example since the background image's origin is the padding box (default) and the background-clip is set to border-box (default). In this case the image isn't being clipped since it fits within the border-box.
- [Background-clip set to `padding-box`](https://jsfiddle.net/ov2sfneg/6/) - Here there is no difference from the default example since the background image's origin is the padding box (default) and the background-clip is set to padding-box. Like in the previous example the image isn't being clipped since it fits within the padding-box.
- [Background-clip set to `content-box`](https://jsfiddle.net/8xzw29g4/7/) - Here you can see that the background is being clipped as the padding applied to the div creates a small content area. The origin of the background image is still the padding-box.

**Background-clip and background-origin used together**

- [Background-clip set to `padding-box` and background-origin set to `content-box`](https://jsfiddle.net/yzoew6gn/8/) (both non-default values) - here you can see the origin of the image has been set to content-box so that it's pushed down and left from it's normal position by the div's padding. Then the background-clip has been set to padding-box so that the image does not show under the bottom or right border (it would if it were set to border-box).

Comment: While I can't argue with direct quotes, they *per se* don't exactly answer the question. In your own words, could you please elaborate on how these properties contrast?

Comment: @chharvey - how's that?

Answer (score 5):

From [CSS3.info](http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/):

The background-origin property is used to determine how the background-position of a background in a certain box is calculated.

The background-clip property is used to determine whether the backgrounds extends into the border or not.

Answer (score 3):

Read this: http://www.css3.info/preview/background-origin-and-background-clip/

'background-clip' is whether the background is in a box, padding or something else!

'background-origin' is used to calculate the position of a certain background in a certain border, padding or somthing else!

Answer (score 2):

This matrix demonstrates the difference and when both are effective:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNVKvj

HTML

```
<h3>Image size default - origin has no impact</h3>
<div class="box box4" > <span>clip:border<br>
  origin:any</span> </div>
<div class="box box1"> <span>clip:padding<br>
  origin:any</span> </div>
<div class="box box7"  > <span>clip:content<br>
  origin:any</span> </div>
<br clear="all"/>
<h3>Image position top, left</h3>
<div class="positioned">
  <div class="box box4"> <span>clip:border<br>
    origin:border</span> </div>
  <div class="box box5"> <span>clip:border<br>
    origin:padding</span> </div>
  <div class="box box6"> <span>clip:border<br>
    origin:content</span> </div>


  <div class="box box1" style="clear:both;"> <span>clip:padding<br>
    origin:border</span> </div>
  <div class="box box2"> <span>clip:padding<br>
    origin:padding</span> </div>
  <div class="box box3"> <span>clip:padding<br>
    origin:content</span> </div>


  <div class="box box7" style="clear:both;"> <span>clip:content<br>
    origin:border</span> </div>
  <div class="box box8"> <span>clip:content<br>
    origin:padding</span> </div>
  <div class="box box9"> <span>clip:content<br>
    origin:content</span> </div>
</div>
<br clear="all"/>

<h3>Image size "contained"</h3>
<div class="contain">

  <div class="box box4"> <span>clip:border<br>
    origin:border</span> </div>
  <div class="box box5"> <span>clip:border<br>
    origin:padding</span> </div>
  <div class="box box6"> <span>clip:border<br>
    origin:content</span> </div>


  <div class="box box1" style="clear:both;"> <span>clip:padding<br>
    origin:border</span> </div>
  <div class="box box2"> <span>clip:padding<br>
    origin:padding</span> </div>
  <div class="box box3"> <span>clip:padding<br>
    origin:content</span> </div>


  <div class="box box7" style="clear:both;"> <span>clip:content<br>
    origin:border</span> </div>
  <div class="box box8"> <span>clip:content<br>
    origin:padding</span> </div>
  <div class="box box9"> <span>clip:content<br>
    origin:content</span> </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box{ background:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/24/Lenna.png) no-repeat center center;  
  width:300px;
  height:300px;  
  border:solid 25px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);  
  padding:25px;
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px; margin-bottom:5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;

}
.contain .box{  
  background-size: contain;
}
.positioned .box{  
  background-position:top left;
}
.box span{color:#fff; text-align:center; display:block; font-size:20px; font-weight:bold; height:100%; background-color:rgba(256,256,256,0.5);}

.box1{
  background-clip:padding-box;
  background-origin:border-box;
}

.box2{
  background-clip:padding-box;
  background-origin:padding-box;
}

.box3{
  background-clip:padding-box;
  background-origin:content-box;
}

.box4{
  background-clip:border-box;
  background-origin:border-box;
}

.box5{
  background-clip:border-box;
  background-origin:padding-box;
}

.box6{
  background-clip:border-box;
  background-origin:content-box;
}

.box7{
  background-clip:content-box;
  background-origin:border-box;
}

.box8{
  background-clip:content-box;
  background-origin:padding-box;
}

.box9{
  background-clip:content-box;
  background-origin:content-box;
}
```

Comment: @j08691 Still loads for me. 20 squares with a lovely lady in them.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it was just earlier today.

Comment: No problem, the internet can be lossy at times.  

If you are curious, the lady is Lenna: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna

Comment: This is a really great answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

> **background-origin**
>
> Before this property, when we added background-image to element the
>   image position was starting at left top of the padding in our element.
>   The background-origin let you to decide where you want the
>   background-position starting point to be, border or padding or
>   content.
>
> The new property of background-origin has 3 values according to the
>   box-model:
>
> border-box - to position the background position 0,0 point at the top
>   left of the border. padding-box(default) - to position the background
>   position 0,0 point at the top left of the padding. content-box - to
>   position the background position 0,0 point at the top left of the
>   content.
>
> **background-clip**
>
> Using background-clip we can decide where to cut the background-image
>   and it is the same as the background origin values as mentioned before
>   .
>
> The new property of background-clip has 3 values:
>
> border-box(default) - to show full image, doesn't cut anything.
>   padding-box - cut the border background-image. content-box - cut the
>   border and padding background-image.

Taken from the link: 
https://coderwall.com/p/h7dwaq/say-hello-to-background-origin-and-background-clip-css3-new-features

Answer (score 2):

### `background-position` vs. `background-origin` vs. `background-clip`

- we can use `background-origin` property to tell at which location from top left corner of container element the background image originates, it does not tell what will happen to the other sides of the image
- `background-position` sets a position relative to the position set by `background-origin`. So if we set `background-origin: content-box` and `background-position: 50px 0px` then position of the background image will be counted from edge of the content box. `background-origin` and `background-position` both individually or together can move the image inside container element
- on the other hand, `background-clip` property sets the part upto which the background image will extend inside a container and then will get clipped. `background-clip` cannot move an image, it only clips it
- using `background-origin` and `background-position` we move the image to a desired position inside container element then using `background-clip` we clip desired parts of the image

[image: background-position vs. background-origin vs. background-clip]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Background Clip</title>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: darkmagenta;
      }
      .container {
        background-image: url(/public/images/flying-bird.jpg);
        font-size: 100px;
        font-weight: 800;
        width: 30%;
        text-align: center;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        /* background-position: 50px 0px; */
        /* background-origin: border-box; */
        /* background-clip: content-box; */
        /* background-clip: text; */
        /* -webkit-background-clip: text; */
        /* color: transparent; */
        padding: 30px;
        border: 20px dashed dodgerblue;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">CSS Magic</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```css
/* background-position only -> add this code above */
.container {
    background-position: 50px 0px;
}
```

```css
/* background-origin only -> add this code above */
.container {
  background-origin: border-box;
}
```

```css
/* background-origin + background-position -> add this code above */
.container {
  background-position: 50px 0px;
  background-origin: border-box;
}
```

```css
/* background-origin + background-position + background-clip -> 
   add this code above */
.container {
  background-position: 50px 0px;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```css
/* background-origin + background-position + background-clip ->
   add this code above */
.container {
  background-position: 50px 0px;
  background-origin: border-box;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a **article** that I wrote on this topic and if anyone really looking forward to see the difference between **background-clip** & **background-origin** then checkout this article.

***Link:*** https://medium.com/@AmJustSam/whats-the-difference-between-background-clip-vs-background-origin-b9a43b4a973

Answer (score 0):

*While doing my own study on CSS, I had this question and came to this thread. Indeed, the two terms create confusion. And as I found out now, there is a subtle difference. While others above have tried to explain it already, I think I can give a simple explanation:*

The difference is in the fact that background-origin starts the background from the specified **top-left corner** (could be either of border-box, content-box, and padding box) and continues to the **end of the border box** (bottom-right corner) irrespective of the specified box. Therefore they are not truly contained inside the specified box. The background-clip property is purely **clipping** or **cropping** the background to the specified box and the **background does not extend over** it even at the bottom-right corner.

This blog has shown a visual demonstration of this difference: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/css-background-clip-vs-background-origin-properties-e2a15d5d7fa0

Answer (score -1):

In Short -

background-origin : specify origin of image

background-clip : specify painting area